# Get the characters after a certain pattern in R - regex

Tags: regex, string, rstudio, text-extraction

I have a data frame with one column:

```
df <- data.frame(cat = c("c(\\\"BPT\\\", \"BP\")", "c(\"BP2\", \"BP\")", "c(\"BPT\", \"BP\")", "c(\"CN\", \"NC\")"))
df$cat <- as.character(df$cat)
df$cat
```

How can I extract the characters that appear after c(\", sometimes there is only one backslash and sometimes there's 2. Similarly with the characters, sometimes the characters are 2 and sometimes they are 3. e.g. BP2, BP etc.

So far I have tried:

```
substr(x = df$cat, start = 4, stop = 6)
```

But this results in:

```
 "\"BP" "BP2"  "BPT"  "CN\""
```

And I only want the output to show

```
"BPT" "BP2"  "BPT"  "CN"
```

Comment: Try `lapply(gsub('\\', '', df$cat, fixed=TRUE), function(x) eval(parse(text=x)))`

Comment: Or `gsub('^c\\(|\\)$|\\\\(")', '\\1', df$cat)`

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew. I tried both, the first one outputs both the texts - BPT and BP. The 2nd piece is also outputting both and I only need one - the first one

Comment: Maybe `lapply(gsub('\\', '', df$cat, fixed=TRUE), function(x) eval(parse(text=x))[[1]])`? Or `unlist(lapply(gsub('\\', '', df$cat, fixed=TRUE), function(x) eval(parse(text=x))[[1]]))`? See https://ideone.com/xImbjP

Comment: Just let know if the first `BP` in your expected output is a typo or not, I understand you need `"BPT" "BP2"  "BPT"  "CN"` and not `"BP" "BP2"  "BPT"  "CN"`

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew. I understand the whole solution with the exception of the 'lapply' part. What is this function doing? function(x) eval(parse(text=x))[[1]] .  Then the lapply part is just applying this function to each output result from.   (Apologies for not putting the code brackets in comments, I tried but didn't work)

Comment: Does that solution work? Is that a typo in your question? Please edit it.

Comment: Yes it was a typo. My great apologies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
df <- data.frame(cat = c("c(\\\"BPT\\\", \"BP\")", "c(\"BP2\", \"BP\")", "c(\"BPT\", \"BP\")", "c(\"CN\", \"NC\")"))
df$cat <- as.character(df$cat)
unlist(lapply(gsub('\\', '', df$cat, fixed=TRUE), function(x) eval(parse(text=x))[[1]]))
## => [1] "BPT" "BP2" "BPT" "CN"
```

See the [R demo online](https://ideone.com/xImbjP).

**Notes**

- `gsub('\\', '', df$cat, fixed=TRUE)` removes all backslashes. You may use `gsub('\\\"', '"', df$cat, fixed=TRUE)` if you only plan to remove backslashes before `"`.
- `eval(parse(text=x))[[1]]` parses the vector and returns the first item
- `lapply` helps traverse the whole data you have. See [Using sapply and lapply](https://www.r-bloggers.com/using-apply-sapply-lapply-in-r/).